# INDEX on DATE field and MONTH() YEAR() functions

Tags: mysql, sql

Is it still correct that an index on a date/datetime column is not optimized for YEAR(col), MONTH(col) functions?  Bill Karwin gave a pretty definitive answer [here](http://forums.mysql.com/read.php?115,86654,86654#msg-86654), but since this was from ten years ago I wanted to check.  I would have thought that since the date column is described as

> A three-byte integer packed as YYYY×16×32 + MM×32 + DD

that it could be indexed in such a way that it could be optimized in the same way that multi column indexes are when a [tight index scan](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/group-by-optimization.html) is performed.

Is it true this optimization still does not exist?  And why wouldn't it be possible?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The problem is not the *representation* of the date.  The problem is the optimization of the query.  When you use `YEAR()` and `MONTH()` on a date column, the column is a function of an argument.

That means that the compiler would  have a lot of information about the function in order to optimize it using an index scan or index lookup.  Such as:

- The function would have to return the same values given the same arguments.
- The function would take only one argument.
- The function would need to be monotonic.
- The function would need to have an inverse (for starting an index scan).

Of course, these things are possible.  The challenge is actually building them into a function definition and into the optimizer.  No one who builds SQL optimizers would want to add special cases for a specific function (well, almost no one; SQL Server does allow some use of `cast()` to take advantage of an index).

So, the answer to your question is that Bill's answer is still valid.

Comment: Thanks for the answer.  I'll need to read some more about the requirement you mention.

Comment: Considering the many uses, Mysql should at the very least support the use of indexes when using `YEAR()`. It's a shame it doesn't.

Answer (score 17):

Correct. MySQL optimizer won't use an index once a column in the WHERE clause is wrapped with a function. The simple reasoning is that once you have an index on column `my_date`, the database sees no point to search in it when you're actually looking for a different value, for example the output of YEAR(my_date).

The good news though are that there is a quick and simple solution in some cases.

For example, the following query can be optimized using a different approach:

```
SELECT flight_company, count(*)
FROM flight_times
WHERE year(FlightDate) = 2017
group by flight_company
```

Instead of using the YEAR() function in the WHERE clause, you can just replace the function call with a range condition that will check the same thing:

```
SELECT flight_company, count(*) 
FROM flight_times
WHERE FlightDate between '2017-01-01'
and '2017-12-31'
GROUP BY flight_company
```

There are functions though that can't simply replaced by a range condition such as in YEAR's case. For example, how would you replace dayofweek() with a condition? Probably harder.
Therefore, another approach is to use MySQL 5.7 [Virtual (generated) columns](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/create-table-generated-columns.html). If you're taking this approach, you can just create this virtual column in your CREATE TABLE statement, to actually match the result of dayofweek():

```
Flight_dayofweek tinyint(4)
 GENERATED ALWAYS AS (dayofweek(FlightDate
 VIRTUAL
```

As the co-founder of EverSQL, I will humbly suggest you to use [EverSQL SQL Query Optimizer](http://www.eversql.com?utm_source=so) to automatically optimize such queries.