# Very slow loop PHP

Tags: php, loops, for-loop, mysqli

I'm a junior dev and i have a problem with a script's loop.
The loop cycles large array came from the DB.
The problem is complete the loop in shortest time is possible, but for now, about 500 elements it takes 15mins to finish.
It's is not acceptable.
The empty space in quotation marks is necessary for my type of file.
This is the code in private class function:

```
$length = count($this->fileH1);
for ($z = 0; $z < $length; $z++) {
    $this->fileH2[$z]['id_paziente'] = $this->fileH1[$z]->id_paziente;
    $this->fileH2[$z]['regione'] = decifra($_SESSION['cod_regione']);
    $this->fileH2[$z]['asl'] = decifra($_SESSION['cod_asl']);
    $this->fileH2[$z]['cod_struttura'] = decifra($_SESSION['cod_struttura']);
    $this->fileH2[$z]['tipo_assist'] = "RIA";
    $this->fileH2[$z]['tipo_strutt'] = decifra($_SESSION['tipo_struttura']);


    // CERCO LE INFO DELLE MENOMAZIONI DEL PAZIENTE
    $stmt_get_info_menomazioni = $this->centro->prepare('SELECT codice, icd9_nuovo FROM tbl_pazienti_terapie_menomazioni WHERE id_paziente = ? AND id_contratto = ? LIMIT 1');
    $stmt_get_info_menomazioni->bind_param("ii", $this->fileH1[$z]->id_paziente, $this->fileH1[$z]->id_contratto); //$fileH1[$z]['id_terapia']);
    $stmt_get_info_menomazioni->execute();
    $stmt_get_info_menomazioni->store_result();
    $stmt_get_info_menomazioni->bind_result($cod_menomazione, $icd9_menomazione);

    if ($stmt_get_info_menomazioni->num_rows > 0) {
        $stmt_get_info_menomazioni->fetch();

        if ($cod_menomazione !== NULL || $cod_menomazione !== '')
            $this->fileH2[$z]['cod_menomazione'] = $cod_menomazione;
        else $this->fileH2[$z]['cod_menomazione'] = '     ';

        if ($icd9_menomazione !== NULL || $icd9_menomazione !== '')
            $this->fileH2[$z]['icd9_menomazione'] = str_pad($icd9_menomazione, 10, " ");
        else $this->fileH2[$z]['icd9_menomazione'] = '          ';

    } else {
        $this->fileH2[$z]['cod_menomazione'] = '     ';
        $this->fileH2[$z]['icd9_menomazione'] = '          ';
    }
    $stmt_get_info_menomazioni->close();


    $this->fileH2[$z]['num_registro'] = $this->fileH1[$z]->anno_rif . decifra($_SESSION['cod_asl']) . '0' . date('y') . str_pad($_POST['mese'], 2, '0', STR_PAD_LEFT) . '0001';;      // "203021040001";      // AGGIUNGERE numero registro struttura
    $this->fileH2[$z]['medico_autorizz'] = '                ';
    $this->fileH2[$z]['cod_medico_autorizz'] = '       ';
    $this->fileH2[$z]['istat_primo_ricovero'] = '000000';
    $this->fileH2[$z]['progressivo'] = $this->fileH1[$z]->progressivo;

    // CERCO LE INFO DELLE TERAPIE DEL PAZIENTE
    $stmt_get_info_menomazioni = $this->centro->prepare('SELECT data_autorizz, data_inizio, data_fine FROM tbl_pazienti_contratti WHERE id_paziente = ? AND id = ? LIMIT 1');
    $stmt_get_info_menomazioni->bind_param("ii", $this->fileH1[$z]->id_paziente, $this->fileH1[$z]->id_contratto); //$fileH1[$z]['id_terapia']);
    $stmt_get_info_menomazioni->execute();
    $stmt_get_info_menomazioni->store_result();
    $stmt_get_info_menomazioni->bind_result($data_autorizz, $data_inizio, $data_fine);
    if ($stmt_get_info_menomazioni->num_rows > 0) {
        $stmt_get_info_menomazioni->fetch();
        if ($data_autorizz !== NULL || $data_autorizz !== '0000-00-00') $this->fileH2[$z]['data_prescrizione'] = date('dmY', strtotime($data_autorizz)); else        $this->fileH2[$z]['data_prescrizione'] = '        ';
        if ($data_inizio !== NULL || $data_inizio !== '0000-00-00') $this->fileH2[$z]['data_inizio_terapia'] = date('dmY', strtotime($data_inizio)); else        $this->fileH2[$z]['data_inizio_terapia'] = '        ';
        if ($data_fine !== NULL || $data_fine !== '0000-00-00') $this->fileH2[$z]['data_fine_terapia'] = date('dmY', strtotime($data_fine)); else        $this->fileH2[$z]['data_fine_terapia'] = '        ';


        // CALCOLO LE DATE DEL CICLO DI FATTURAZIONE
        $data_inizio_mese_attuale = date('Y-m-1');
        $data_inizio_terapia = date('Y-m-d', strtotime($data_inizio));
        if ($data_inizio_mese_attuale < $data_inizio_terapia)
            $this->fileH2[$z]['data_inizio_periodo_fatturazione'] = date('dmY', strtotime($data_inizio_terapia));
        else $this->fileH2[$z]['data_inizio_periodo_fatturazione'] = date('dmY', strtotime($data_inizio_mese_attuale));

        $data_fine_mese_attuale = date('Y-m-t');  // t = ultimo gg del mese attuale
        $data_fine_terapia = date('Y-m-d', strtotime($data_fine));
        if ($data_fine_mese_attuale > $data_fine_terapia)
            $this->fileH2[$z]['data_fine_periodo_fatturazione'] = date('dmY', strtotime($data_fine_terapia));
        else $this->fileH2[$z]['data_fine_periodo_fatturazione'] = date('dmY', strtotime($data_fine_mese_attuale));


        // CALCOLO QTA PRESTAZIONI EFFETTUATE
        $stmt_get_qta_prestaz_eff = $this->centro->prepare('SELECT COUNT(id) FROM tbl_pazienti_terapie_presenze WHERE MONTH(DATE(ingresso_effettuato)) = ? AND id_paziente = ?');
        $stmt_get_qta_prestaz_eff->bind_param('ii', $this->mese, $this->fileH1[$z]->id_paziente);
        $stmt_get_qta_prestaz_eff->execute();
        $stmt_get_qta_prestaz_eff->store_result();
        $stmt_get_qta_prestaz_eff->bind_result($qta_prestaz);
        $stmt_get_qta_prestaz_eff->fetch();

        $this->fileH2[$z]['qta_prestaz'] = str_pad($qta_prestaz, 3, "0", STR_PAD_LEFT);


        $this->fileH2[$z]['codifica_nomencl'] = 't';

        if ($this->fileH2[$z]['progressivo'] == '99')
            $this->fileH2[$z]['codice_prestaz'] = '       ';
        else $this->fileH2[$z]['codice_prestaz'] = '001.001';

        $this->fileH2[$z]['esenzione_1'] = '0';
        $this->fileH2[$z]['esenzione_2'] = '      ';
        $this->fileH2[$z]['esenzione_3'] = '0';

        $this->fileH2[$z]['onere'] = "1";
        $this->fileH2[$z]['importo_compart'] = '000000,00';
        $this->fileH2[$z]['posizione_compart'] = '0';

        if ($this->fileH1[$z]->tariffa !== NULL || $this->fileH1[$z]->tariffa !== '')
            $this->fileH2[$z]['importo_totale'] = str_replace('.', ',', str_pad(floatval($this->fileH1[$z]->tariffa) * $qta_prestaz, 9, "0", STR_PAD_LEFT));
        else $this->fileH2[$z]['importo_totale'] = "         ";

        $stmt_get_qta_prestaz_eff->close();

    }
    $stmt_get_info_menomazioni->close();

    $this->fileH2[$z]['posizione_contab'] = ' ';
    $this->fileH2[$z]['err01'] = ' ';
    $this->fileH2[$z]['err02'] = ' ';
    $this->fileH2[$z]['err03'] = ' ';
    $this->fileH2[$z]['err04'] = ' ';
    $this->fileH2[$z]['err05'] = ' ';
    $this->fileH2[$z]['err06'] = ' ';
    $this->fileH2[$z]['err07'] = ' ';
    $this->fileH2[$z]['err08'] = ' ';
    $this->fileH2[$z]['err09'] = ' ';
    $this->fileH2[$z]['err10'] = ' ';

    $this->fileH2[$z]['anno_rif'] = $this->fileH1[$z]->anno_rif;
    $this->fileH2[$z]['cod_strut_erog'] = decifra($_SESSION['cod_struttura_eroga']);
    $this->fileH2[$z]['identificativo_mensile'] = $this->fileH1[$z]->identificativo_mensile;

    $this->fileH2[$z]['anno_mese_invio'] = date('Ym');
    $this->fileH2[$z]['asl_addebito'] = 000;
}
```

Someone can help me?

**UPDATE 1:**
First thanks all for the answer.
Make a unique call with JOIN and move out of loop the prepare statment. Now the time for about 500 item is 5mins.

```
$sql = 'SELECT COUNT(tp.id),pc.data_autorizz, pc.data_inizio, pc.data_fine, tm.codice, tm.icd9_nuovo FROM tbl_pazienti_terapie_presenze as tp LEFT JOIN tbl_pazienti_contratti as pc ON tp.id_paziente = pc.id_paziente LEFT JOIN tbl_pazienti_terapie_menomazioni as tm ON tm.id_contratto = pc.id AND tm.id_paziente = pc.id_paziente WHERE MONTH(DATE(tp.ingresso_effettuato)) = ? AND tp.id_paziente = ? AND pc.id = ?';
    $do_sql = $this->centro->prepare($sql);
    $length = count($this->fileH1);
    for ($z = 0; $z < $length; $z++) {
        $this->fileH2[$z]['id_paziente'] = $this->fileH1[$z]['id_paziente'];['id_terapia'];
        $this->fileH2[$z]['regione'] = decifra($_SESSION['cod_regione']);
        $this->fileH2[$z]['asl'] = decifra($_SESSION['cod_asl']);
        $this->fileH2[$z]['cod_struttura'] = decifra($_SESSION['cod_struttura']);
        $this->fileH2[$z]['tipo_assist'] = "RIA";
        $this->fileH2[$z]['tipo_strutt'] = decifra($_SESSION['tipo_struttura']);

        $do_sql->bind_param('iii', $this->mese, $this->fileH1[$z]['id_paziente'], $this->fileH1[$z]['id_contratto']);
        $do_sql->execute();
        $do_sql->store_result();
        $do_sql->bind_result($qta_prestaz, $data_autorizz, $data_inizio, $data_fine, $cod_menomazione, $icd9_menomazione);
        if ($do_sql->num_rows > 0) {
            $do_sql->fetch();

            if ($cod_menomazione !== NULL && $cod_menomazione !== '')
                $this->fileH2[$z]['cod_menomazione'] = $cod_menomazione;
            else $this->fileH2[$z]['cod_menomazione'] = '     ';

            if ($icd9_menomazione !== NULL && $icd9_menomazione !== '')
                $this->fileH2[$z]['icd9_menomazione'] = str_pad($icd9_menomazione, 10, " ");
            else $this->fileH2[$z]['icd9_menomazione'] = '          ';

            if ($data_autorizz !== NULL && $data_autorizz !== '0000-00-00') $this->fileH2[$z]['data_prescrizione'] = date('dmY', strtotime($data_autorizz)); else        $this->fileH2[$z]['data_prescrizione'] = '        ';
            if ($data_inizio !== NULL && $data_inizio !== '0000-00-00') $this->fileH2[$z]['data_inizio_terapia'] = date('dmY', strtotime($data_inizio)); else        $this->fileH2[$z]['data_inizio_terapia'] = '        ';
            if ($data_fine !== NULL && $data_fine !== '0000-00-00') $this->fileH2[$z]['data_fine_terapia'] = date('dmY', strtotime($data_fine)); else        $this->fileH2[$z]['data_fine_terapia'] = '        ';


            if ($this->fileH1[$z]['tariffa'] !== NULL || $this->fileH1[$z]['tariffa'] !== '')
                $this->fileH2[$z]['importo_totale'] = str_replace('.', ',', str_pad(floatval($this->fileH1[$z]->tariffa) * $qta_prestaz, 9, "0", STR_PAD_LEFT));
            else $this->fileH2[$z]['importo_totale'] = '         ';

            $this->fileH2[$z]['codifica_nomencl'] = 't';

            if ($this->fileH2[$z]['progressivo'] == '99')
                $this->fileH2[$z]['codice_prestaz'] = '       ';
            else $this->fileH2[$z]['codice_prestaz'] = '001.001';

            $this->fileH2[$z]['esenzione_1'] = '0';
            $this->fileH2[$z]['esenzione_2'] = '      ';
            $this->fileH2[$z]['esenzione_3'] = '0';

            $this->fileH2[$z]['onere'] = "1";
            $this->fileH2[$z]['importo_compart'] = '000000,00';
            $this->fileH2[$z]['posizione_compart'] = '0';

            // CALCOLO LE DATE DEL CICLO DI FATTURAZIONE
            $data_inizio_mese_attuale = date('Y-m-1');
            $data_inizio_terapia = date('Y-m-d', strtotime($data_inizio));
            if ($data_inizio_mese_attuale < $data_inizio_terapia)
                $this->fileH2[$z]['data_inizio_periodo_fatturazione'] = date('dmY', strtotime($data_inizio_terapia));
            else $this->fileH2[$z]['data_inizio_periodo_fatturazione'] = date('dmY', strtotime($data_inizio_mese_attuale));

            $data_fine_mese_attuale = date('Y-m-t');  // t = ultimo gg del mese attuale
            $data_fine_terapia = date('Y-m-d', strtotime($data_fine));
            if ($data_fine_mese_attuale > $data_fine_terapia)
                $this->fileH2[$z]['data_fine_periodo_fatturazione'] = date('dmY', strtotime($data_fine_terapia));
            else $this->fileH2[$z]['data_fine_periodo_fatturazione'] = date('dmY', strtotime($data_fine_mese_attuale));

            $this->fileH2[$z]['num_registro'] = $this->fileH1[$z]['anno_rif'] . decifra($_SESSION['cod_asl']) . '0' . date('y') . str_pad($_POST['mese'], 2, '0', STR_PAD_LEFT) . '0001';;      // "203021040001";      // AGGIUNGERE numero registro struttura
            $this->fileH2[$z]['medico_autorizz'] = '                ';
            $this->fileH2[$z]['cod_medico_autorizz'] = '       ';
            $this->fileH2[$z]['istat_primo_ricovero'] = '000000';
            $this->fileH2[$z]['progressivo'] = $this->fileH1[$z]['progressivo'];

        }

        $this->fileH2[$z]['posizione_contab'] = ' ';
        $this->fileH2[$z]['err01'] = ' ';
        $this->fileH2[$z]['err02'] = ' ';
        $this->fileH2[$z]['err03'] = ' ';
        $this->fileH2[$z]['err04'] = ' ';
        $this->fileH2[$z]['err05'] = ' ';
        $this->fileH2[$z]['err06'] = ' ';
        $this->fileH2[$z]['err07'] = ' ';
        $this->fileH2[$z]['err08'] = ' ';
        $this->fileH2[$z]['err09'] = ' ';
        $this->fileH2[$z]['err10'] = ' ';

        $this->fileH2[$z]['anno_rif'] = $this->fileH1[$z]['anno_rif'];
        $this->fileH2[$z]['cod_strut_erog'] = decifra($_SESSION['cod_struttura_eroga']);
        $this->fileH2[$z]['identificativo_mensile'] = $this->fileH1[$z]['identificativo_mensile'];

        $this->fileH2[$z]['anno_mese_invio'] = date('Ym');
        $this->fileH2[$z]['asl_addebito'] = 000;
    $do_sql->close();
```

better than before but still not acceptable

**UPDATE 2:**
After some testing i found that this query `COUNT(id) FROM tbl_pazienti_terapie_presenze WHERE MONTH(ingresso_effettuato) = ? AND id_paziente = ?` causes the severe slowdown. I have no idea why this happens.

**SOLUTION:**
Thanks all for the answer.
The problem is the query function MONTH(). Although the field is indexed, the function MONTH() skips the index and consequently slows down the query.
Replacing it with
e.g.
`WHERE ingresso_effettuato BETWEEN '2021-12-01 00:00:00', '2021-12-31 23:59:59'`
or
`WHERE ingresso_effettuato >= '2021-12-01 00:00:00' AND ingresso_effettuato <= '2021-12-31 23:59:59'` the problem is fixed.

Comment: _Small Point_ Cramming an IF statement onto a single line does not speed anything up, it just slows down the poor dev that follows you and has to work out what is going on

Comment: Please show us the results of `SHOW KEYS FROM tbl_pazienti_terapie_menomazioni`.  For each table you are using please.

Comment: What have you tried to check which parts are slow? What have you tried to resolve the problem itself?

Comment: The general logic of `if (x !== NULL || x != '')` is always true.  Probably mean to use `&&`.

Comment: Thanks all to answer. @NicoHaase after a test, if i remove the mysqli call the loop is quick.

Comment: @HoldOffHunger this is the answer about your query:       tbl_pazienti_terapie_menomazioni:  Non_unique: 0  Key_name: PRIMARY Seq_in_index:1  Cardinality:34628                                                                tbl_pazienti_terapie_presenze: Non_unique: 0 Key_name: PRIMARY,id Seq_in_index:1 Comlumn_name:id  Cardinality:97448                                                               tbl_pazienti_terapie_contratti: Non_unique: 0  Key_name: PRIMARY,id,id_paziente,num_pratica Seq_in_index:1  Cardinality:34628

Comment: If you are facing any database-related problems, please share more details, like the execution plan for the slow query

Comment: @NicoHaase The DB doesn't have problem, in the throughout the application it works well and is also fast. Only this function causes this slowdown.

Comment: Are `id_paziente` and/or `id_contratto` unique per table? If so, you could simply make a _single_ `WHERE id_contratto IN (?, ?, ?, ? ... )` query, rather than 500 queries. You could likely also combine all that into a single JOIN query. That would be a LOT lighter to execute. Further, you would get more insights if you created and provided a minimal reproducible example; https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: In general, if you have a sluggish query, you probably have an issue with your indexes. Here you have a function in the query: `MONTH(ingresso_effettuato) = ? AND id_paziente` and as such, MySQL won't use an index for the lookup. Anything you can do to create a function-free query? See: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40252101/index-on-date-field-and-month-year-functions

Comment: So, what’s the current state of your problem? Is the DB query the problem now (as added to the question) or not (as stated in the comment section)? If it is: what did you try to check why? Does the execution plan for that query show new insights?

Comment: @MarkusAO thanks, i fix my problem after remove the MONTH() function. Now the DB index work right

Comment: Great to hear. I'm curious, how long does the loop take now?

Comment: @MarkusAO Now the time for about 2000 item in array to loop is 20secs.

Comment: Well that's definitely an improvement. What's the baseline time if you remove all the other stuff and just loop the queries?

Comment: If i remove all, the time , always 2000 item, is 15/16secs

Comment: Right so that's the baseline for the queries. See if you can work out my earlier suggestion on using `IN(...)` to fetch everything in one go, instead of separate queries. It should dramatically cut down the processing time.

Answer (score 0):

There are mulitple Reasons why your code might be slow.

In PHP it is often caused by misusing the Database. First of all you need setup indexes on your tables, especially for the fields which youre using for your SELECT statement.

Also since PHP have to connect to a database over a network, your code might be slower if your database is on different server than your webserver ist. Some Hosting Providers use different networks for Databases. Because of this it is crutial to make as less calls to the database as possible.

In your script i saw that you use prepare(), execute(), close() and this 3 times. Which means that you go to the database and execute some actions there. This might lead to slower performance as well.

I made a little performance test to show that there is a difference between using preapre statement within a loop and ouside:

```
<?php
error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set('display_errors','On');

$mysqli = new mysqli('db','db','db','db');

$queries = 100;

$start = microtime(true);

$resultId = null;
$resultTest = null;
for($i=0;$i<=100;$i++){
    $id = 1;

    $sql = "SELECT id,test FROM test WHERE id = ?";
    $statement = $mysqli->prepare($sql);
    $statement->bind_param('i',$id);
    $statement->execute();
    $statement->store_result();
    $statement->bind_result($resultId,$resultTest);
    $statement->close();

    $id = 2;
    $sql = "SELECT id,test FROM test WHERE id = ?";
    $statement = $mysqli->prepare($sql);
    $statement->bind_param('i',$id);
    $statement->execute();
    $statement->store_result();
    $statement->bind_result($resultId,$resultTest);
    $statement->close();

    $id = 3;
    $sql = "SELECT id,test FROM test WHERE id = ?";
    $statement = $mysqli->prepare($sql);
    $statement->bind_param('i',$id);
    $statement->execute();
    $statement->store_result();
    $statement->bind_result($resultId,$resultTest);
    $statement->close();

}

$end = microtime(true);
$diff = $end-$start;
echo "Prepare statements inside loop time: ".$diff."<br/>";


$start = microtime(true);

 $sql = "SELECT id,test FROM test WHERE id = ?";
$statement1 = $mysqli->prepare($sql);
$statement2 = $mysqli->prepare($sql);
$statement3 = $mysqli->prepare($sql);

for($i=0;$i<=100;$i++){
    $id = 1;


    $statement1->bind_param('i',$id);
    $statement1->execute();
    $statement1->store_result();
    $statement1->bind_result($resultId,$resultTest);


    $id = 2;

    $statement2->bind_param('i',$id);
    $statement2->execute();
    $statement2->store_result();
    $statement2->bind_result($resultId,$resultTest);


    $id = 3;

    $statement3->bind_param('i',$id);
    $statement3->execute();
    $statement3->store_result();
    $statement3->bind_result($resultId,$resultTest);


}
$statement1->close();
$statement2->close();
$statement3->close();

$end = microtime(true);
$diff = $end-$start;
echo "Prepare statements only execute time: ".$diff."<br/>";
```

Results are

```
Prepare statements inside loop time: 0.046118021011353
Prepare statements only execute time: 0.020095109939575
```

So i would suggest in first place to move your statements outside of the loop, then check your indexes.

To do so. You can write down one of your SQL Queries with Real values and execute your SELECT statement with a DESCRIBE in PHPMyadmin

e.g.

```
DESCRIBE SELECT COUNT(id) FROM tbl_pazienti_terapie_presenze WHERE MONTH(DATE(ingresso_effettuato)) = 12 AND id_paziente = 1336
```

in the Result you will see if there are indexes used or not, if not then you need to created the index for this field.

And often the SQL queries can be combined with a join since you reuse the ID in 3 differnt SQL queries the Tables must somehow to be relateable so they might be able to be joined together to one statement.

Iam not sure if this answer will fix your speed problem but at least you have some clues where you can optimize.

Comment: You dont HAVE TO, but it is a better way to do it

Comment: @RiggsFolly but he has 3 prepared statements within the loop and also he closes the connection within the loop, iam pretty sure that his MIGHT have performance issues to open up everytime the connection

Comment: Yes you are right, but the word HAVE TO assume there would be an error if you didnt and there wont be an error, just a slow loop :)

Comment: Please share more details such that others can learn from your answer. Is this really the fix for the slow loop? Or just a side-comment that should rather be posted as a comment?

Comment: Also, without knowing what `$this->centro->prepare` returns, it's guessing that calling `close` on that will really close the whole database connection. For example, PHP's own PDO class does not have a built-in function called `close`

Comment: @NicoHaase yes he is not using PDO here, it is mysqli, because of store_result(), bind_param and bind_result. PDO use CamelCase

Comment: @VitalijMik Thanks, this method improves but does not fix the problem. However, it takes too long